# Write $x$ in three orthogonal directions $\vec{r}$, $\vec{s}$, and $\vec{r}\times\vec{s}$ given some interesting conditions.

Tags: vectors, solution-verification

This is a problem from Bressoud "Second Year Calculus" Exercise 19 Section 2.5. It gives the conditions $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{s}=0$, and $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{x}=c$, and $\vec{r}\times\vec{x}=\vec{s}$. Find $x$ in each of the three mutually orthogonal directions, $\vec{r}$, $\vec{s}$, and $\vec{r}\times\vec{s}$.

So far $\vec{x_r}=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{r}}{|r|}\frac{\vec{r}}{|r|}=\frac{c}{|r|^2}\vec{r}$, and $\vec{x_s}=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{s}}{|s|}\frac{\vec{s}}{|s|}=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{r}\times\vec{x})}{|s|}\frac{\vec{s}}{|s|}=0$ Since $\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{r}\times\vec{x})$ is the volumn of a degenerate parallelepiped. Where I'm having most difficulty is in...

$\vec{x_{\vec{r}\times\vec{s}}}=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{r}\times\vec{s})}{|\vec{r}\times\vec{s}|^2}\vec{r}\times\vec{s}$. Since $r$ and $s$ are orthogonal does that mean $|\vec{r}\times\vec{s}|=|r||s|$. And also can I calculate $\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{r}\times\vec{s})$ using the triple product to be $|r||s||\vec{x_{s\perp}}|=|r||s||\vec{x}-\vec{x_{s}}|=|r||s||\vec{x}|$. Is there a simpler simplification of this?

So does $\vec{x_{\vec{r}\times\vec{s}}}=\frac{|\vec{x}|}{|\vec{r}||\vec{s}|}\vec{x}$?

Comment: I got $ - \frac{1}{|r|^2}$

Comment: @dinush for which value?

Comment: I posted it try it

Comment: for  $\vec x_{\vec r \times \vec s}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to simplify the notation a bit, let $\vec t = \vec r \times \vec s$.

Because $\vec x_{\vec s} = 0$, we know $\vec x = \vec x_{\vec r} + \vec x_{\vec t}$. Therefore
$$
   \vec r \times \vec x = \vec s \implies \vec r \times (\vec x_{\vec r} + \vec x_{\vec t}) = \vec s \implies \vec r \times \vec x_{\vec r} +  \vec r \times \vec x_{\vec t} = \vec s.
$$
But $\vec r \times \vec x_{\vec r} = 0$, so we conclude that $\vec r \times \vec x_{\vec t} = \vec s$. Moreover, $\vec r$ and $\vec x_{\vec t}$ are orthogonal, so $|\vec r| |\vec x_{\vec t}| = |\vec s|$.

This tells us $|\vec x_{\vec t}| = \frac{|\vec s|}{|\vec r|}$, so $\vec x_{\vec t} = \pm \frac{|\vec s|}{|\vec r|} \frac{\vec t}{|\vec t|} = \pm \frac{|\vec s|}{|\vec r||\vec t|} \vec t$.  We also know $|\vec t| = |\vec r| |\vec s|$, further simplifying $\vec x_{\vec t}$ to $\pm \frac1{|\vec r|^2} \vec t$.

Which sign is it? Well, we want $\vec r \times \vec x_{\vec t} = \vec s$, but $\vec r \times \vec t$ is proportional to $-\vec s$. Therefore $\vec x_{\vec t} = -\frac1{|\vec r|^2} \vec t$.

Answer (score 1):

consider $\vec r\times\vec x=\vec s$

taking cross product from both sides

$$\vec r\times(\vec r\times\vec x)=\vec r\times\vec s$$
you can use vector triple cross product formula

then $$(\vec r.\vec x)\vec r-(\vec r.\vec r)\vec x=\vec r\times\vec s$$
$$(\vec r.\vec x)\vec r-|\vec r|^2\vec x=\vec r\times\vec s$$
rearranging $$\vec x=\frac{c}{|\vec r|^2} \vec r-\frac{1}{|\vec r|^2}\vec r\times\vec s$$
since $\vec r$,$\vec s$ and  $\vec r\times\vec s$ are mutually orthogonal they are linearly independent therefore you can get $\vec x$, as a linear combination of these $\vec r$,$\vec s$ and  $\vec r\times\vec s$ vectors

$$\vec x=\frac{c}{|\vec r|^2} \vec r-\frac{1}{|\vec r|^2}\vec (r\times\vec s)-0\vec s$$
so you can take component as
$$\vec x_\vec r=\frac{c}{|\vec r|^2} $$
$$\vec x_{\vec r \times \vec s}=\frac{-1}{|\vec r|^2}$$
and $$\vec x_\vec s= 0 $$